# How to get related content WITHOUT using tags?

Tags: php

I need a way to get related content without using tags because in my case there are too many tags and those tags are inserted by users ( so in the most case they forgot to use them ).

Youtube do the same thing: if, for example, you are watching a funny video, then youtube show you other funny videos in the related content.

For instance, if the article's title is "Barack Obama, president of USA, go to Miami", I need to get other articles that contain "Barack Obama", "USA", "president" or "Miami" in the title and, if possible, other articles of the same topic.

THIS CAN BE VERY COMPLEX TO DO, so I asked you for some advice.

Comment: This will be seriously hard to get right, unless you do something of questionable quality, like just search every term except for articles/common words (e.g. videos relating to `["Barack", "Obama", "president", "USA", "Miami"]`).  Interestingly enough, this ends up just basically giving you tags.  I think if you let the users specify the tags, you'll end up with higher quality.

Comment: First thing I can suggest is to make a cron job that calculates these (and this can be very inefficient as it will run one per day or something like that) - and you insert your relations in a table. I'll think about the actual search part :)

Comment: At first step you could prepare a list of bad words (the, a, an, at and so on), know the unpluralize version of each words (maybe u could find a web service), and generate a tagging system from this scratch. Mind the performance of such approach.

Comment: You might want to consider using FullText Search for such a usecase for example like here http://forum.codecall.net/topic/50985-using-fulltext-searches-with-php-and-mysql/#axzz2Iygk1QjC

Comment: User defining tags are trickier. Excluding all above advice which i won't repeat, you'l have to take account of incorrected tags. E.g. Obama/oboma. Or more specific, USA will point to same as UNITED STATES OF AMERICA. You'l also have to make relations for it in which case, the results will be more accurate even if the users doesn't know the appropriate tags.

Comment: Do you have a specific target area in terms of articles or is it more like youtube where the topic can be anything? I am asking this to evaluate how good would an approach to auto tag posts in the background to co-relate them would be

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is to use Zend Lucene.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.html

It's an easy to implement search engine that runs entirely in php. You can use it a component separate from Zend Framework, and it's fairly easy to implement.

Index all your contents. Use the (for some reason undocumented) boost feature to make parts of the content that more relevant (IE. title, user tags)
Example here: http://davedash.com/2007/05/29/boosting-terms-in-zend-search-lucene/

Then, use the title as a keyword query and display the x highest scoring results to your users. (making sure to filter the content the user is currently looking at)

For optimization you could cash the search results per page.

You can tweak outcomes:
- What content best describes the content - Boost those items while indexing
- When searching what will you use (Title, User Tag, combination)